# Ordinal numbers

Tags: terminology, article-writing

I have a sequence of coefficients. I can obviously write "i-th" or "h-th coefficient", but I'm referring to the coefficient with number n-h. Can I write "(n-h)-th coefficient"?

Comment: This is hard to understand. Perhaps an example of what you mean might clarify things. Do you mean $n-h$ (minus sign)? In this case, it is probably okay to write $(n-h)$-th coefficient.

Comment: Yes. See section 5.5 of Nick Higham's book on mathematical style: https://books.google.com/books?id=bwj572k-lnEC&lpg=PA32&vq=(n%2B1)th&dq=%22Handbook%20of%20Writing%20for%20the%20Mathematical%20Sciences%22%20ordinal&pg=PR1#v=onepage&q=ordinal&f=false